# I'm getting the following error "Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node'"

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to create a program that clones a form based on the number the user inputs on field
since I'm new to javascript, I was at first trying to make it work with a

and I was able to do so.

But to my surprise, as soon as a I added a nested form (form2) inside my other form, my code stopped working =/.

I've already tried adding differnt elements to my form (DIVs, Lists, etc) and all seem to work.

Is there an error I'm not seeing?

Please help

HTML code that does work as expected:

```
<html>
   <head>
     <title></title>
   </head>
   <body bgcolor= #30CF9A>
     <form id="form1">
       <input type="text" id="input1">
       <input type="text" id="input2">
       <p id="p1">Hello</p>
       <p id="p2">joya</p>
       <button type="button" id="sosboton">boton</button>
     </form>
     <script src="test.js"></script>
   </body>
```

HTML code that doesn't work:

```
<html>
   <head>
     <title></title>
   </head>
   <body bgcolor= #30CF9A>
     <form id="form1">
       <input type="text" id="input1">
       <input type="text" id="input2">
       <p id="p1">Hello</p>
       <p id="p2">joya</p>
       <form id="form2">
         <p>HOLA!</p>
       </form>
       <button type="button" id="sosboton">boton</button>
     </form>
     <script src="test.js"></script>
   </body>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
var inp = document.getElementById('input1');
inp.onchange = function () {cambio()};

function cambio(){
  var $x = inp.value
  for (let y = 0; y < $x; y++) {
    let $form = document.getElementById('form1');
    let $p2 = document.getElementById('p2');
    let $cln = $p2.cloneNode(true);
    $cln.id = (`autogen${y}`);
    $form.insertBefore($cln, sosboton);
  }
}
```

Comment: two things, I don't think you should nest forms, secondly, I don't see where sosboton is coming from in your last line, shhould this be a variable or a string in ""?

Comment: @bigmadwolf Browsers will make elements available globally by their id by attaching them to `window[id]`, so in this case `sosboton` would be the button node itself.

Comment: @CollinD I did not know that.  amazing. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with HTML, that doesn't allow to nest forms.

I've ended up using a DIV inside the original form and duplicating that DIV